# Password is in a different language

Tags: password, language

I just opened my new MacBook Air and I noticed that when my computer asks for my password, the tinted word that should say "Password" (before I type it) is in a different language. How do I change it to English?

Answer (score 1):

I've had this happen with a couple of new Macs at our office recently.  I'm not sure if something is off with Apple's latest imaging of new Macs but the fix is relatively simple.

- Login as normal, using your regular password.
- Click on the  menu in the upper left corner and choose System Preferences (4th choice down)

  [image]
- Click on Language & Region
  [image]
- Change the following

  - If English is already an option then drag it to the top of the list
  - Click the + symbol in the lower left to add English to the list of languages
  - Change the region to the appropriate one (Americas, North America, United States)

[image]

- Click "Show All" to leave the preference pane and return to System Preferences.  Your language should now be set to English.  You might restart your Mac to make sure.

Comment: If that doesn't work, try using the minus button to delete all languages other than English and restarting.  If that also doesn't work, try http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4102